# Como colocar background Auto Ajustavel?

Tags: css, css3

Como colocar fundo auto ajustável à tela?

Coloquei assim no meu `body` mas quando entro no celular ele fica cortando o background, só fica até onde tem elemento.

```
body{
    clear: both;  
    background:url(../img/background-login.png) center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -khtml-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
     min-height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Mesmo assim ainda nao consegui :/

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar `100% 100%` use `cover`.

```
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-khtml-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
```

A diferença é que com `100% 100%` ele vai atingir sempre o máximo de 100% seja ele, vertical ou horizontal. Já o `cover` irá 'cobrir' a `div`. Mas, em contra partida, ele pode cortar (e certamente irá) cortar ou um pouco das laterais, ou do topo e rodapé da imagem.

---

Editado:

Tente isso:

```
body,html {
    min-height:100%;
    //ou
    min-height:100% !important; //Use somente se este não estender o `body`
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma nao deu amigo

Comment: Editei minha resposta, tente.

Comment: tentei com min-height tbm e nao consegui

Comment: se eu for pelo computador e clicar no debug do f12 e ver como se fosse mobile funciona normal agora se eu vor no celular mesmo nao funciona coloquei dessa forma . 
body{
clear: both;  
background:url(../img/background-login.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-khtml-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
     min-height:100% !important;
  
}

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o seu body e o css lá, fica mais fácil de visualizar. De preferência todo o css que envolva ele.

Comment: Celsom pude perceber que quando retiro o no-repeat ele funciona porem repete mas prenche a tela toda , e nao quero que ele faça isso , vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: o seu background, ele está assim: `url(../img/background-login.png)` ele deve ter aspas, assim: `url('../img/background-login.png');` Tente ;)

Comment: mesmo com as aspas não funcionou , e estou achando engraçado que apenas no celular o background nao fica auto ajustavel , agora se for no f12 do  google chrome e selecionar aparelho mobile funciona

Comment: @VictorMorais tente este exemplo fornecido pelo Bacco, veja se resolve: https://jsfiddle.net/hne7x31f/3/

Answer (score -1):

Por favor,tente:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Comment: ou assim também

<pre>background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;

Comment: infelizmente a sua resposta não serve. A propriedade 'contain' não vai preencher o espaço da div. Ele vai funcionar de modo semelhante ao `100% 100%`, indo até largura ou altura máxima.

Comment: dessa forma nao deu amigo